# Extract Microsoft Graph Chart Object from Excel file

Tags: php, excel, graph, charts, mschart

I need to extract Microsoft Graph Chart that is embedded in Ms Excel files externally and save it to MySQL database. The data I need is the value in the datasheet that made up the chart. (It appears when you double click the chart). I have tried to use PHP Excel library, but it can only access the data in the cells, not embedded object's data.

I am open to use any tool, PHP, PERL, Python, Java or anything as long as I can get the job done.

Sample excel file that contain the embedded Ms Graph Chart : http://www.sendspace.com/file/8rd1jg

Any information/thoughts will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using C# or VB.Net (and the document was created with Excel 2007 or 2010), I'd suggest using the [OpenXML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).

Here are a few resources that you might find useful:

- http://www.codeshelve.com/code/details/48/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850837.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc820055.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I doubt it's a Microsoft Graph object in the Excel workbook. Microsoft Graph was the applet used by PowerPoint and Word to insert charts in Office 2003 and earlier.

So if you have to hunt in Google for help, you'll find more information, which is more relevant, if you search for Excel Chart, rather than Microsoft Graph.